# Possible to get file data/val from a file upload input and send it to server with an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, upload

Basically the below fires right after you click browse and
select a file.

I just need a single file upload done of the file the user selects
through the regular file input type and I want it to fire right after
the file is selected and done asynchronously in the background.

```
<input type="file" name="imagefile" size="20" />

$('input[type="file"]').change(function () {

    var $file = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/BannerImageUpload",
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: { file: $file },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Load was performed.');
        }


    });

});
```

Comment: You're better off [not doing this yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery#).

Comment: Here is what appears to be a simple script, if you're trying to avoid bloat: http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/iframe-post-form.html

Comment: Hmm, I see. HTML5 does allow file uploads using Ajax though so I may look into that. This is for Admin area so backwards compatibility with older browsers is not important.

Comment: Not to toot my own blog but have you looked into the `FileApi`? http://buildstarted.com/2011/07/17/asp-net-mvc-3-file-uploads-using-the-fileapi/

Comment: [BlueImp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js#L76) uses a `canvas` to to get the data from the image/file selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) to asynchronously upload files assuming the client browser supports it. Take a look at the *Example: Uploading a user-selected file* section towards the end of the documentation I've linked to if you want to see the necessary steps to implement it.

Another possibility is to use an existing ready-to-be-used AJAX file upload component such as [Blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) which implements this functionality. The pros of using such a control is that it will fallback to standard uploading mechanisms if the browser doesn't support HTML5.